# Trouble connecting to AMQP adapter in OpenShift

Tags: eclipse-hono

I'm trying to create an MQTT Protocol Gateway for our Hono Cluster running in OpenShift
using [this template](https://github.com/eclipse-hono/hono-extras/tree/master/protocol-gateway/mqtt-protocol-gateway-template) but I am having trouble connecting to the AMQP adapter.

I can connect to the Sandbox AMQP adapter using the CLI (version 2.1.0) but when I try to connect to the instance running in our cluster I get "503 - Temporary unavailable".

[image]

I have tried many variants of this command, but I discovered I get the exact same error seemingly no matter what host I call in OpenShift, including hosts not even running in our Hono cluster, and I don't know what that means.

I have verified the cluster installation in so far that all the pods look healthy and I have been able to create tenants and devices and I can send telemetry to the HTTP adapter.

SERVICES
[image: $ oc get service NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE hono-poc-adapter-amqp ClusterIP 172.30.197.58 5672/TCP,5671/TCP 17d hono-poc-adapter-http ClusterIP 172.30.212.47 8080/TCP,8443/TCP 17d hono-poc-adapter-mqtt ClusterIP 172.30.2.192 1883/TCP,8883/TCP 17d hono-poc-kafka ClusterIP 172.30.252.145 9092/TCP 17d hono-poc-kafka-0-external NodePort 172.30.145.109 9094:32094/TCP 17d hono-poc-kafka-headless ClusterIP None 9092/TCP,9093/TCP 17d hono-poc-monogodb-server ClusterIP 172.30.53.142 27017/TCP 17d hono-poc-service-auth ClusterIP 172.30.226.82 5671/TCP,8088/TCP 17d hono-poc-service-command-router ClusterIP 172.30.93.170 5671/TCP 17d hono-poc-service-device-registry ClusterIP 172.30.217.54 5671/TCP,8080/TCP,8443/TCP 17d hono-poc-service-device-registry-ext ClusterIP 172.30.170.109 28080/TCP,28443/TCP 17d hono-poc-zookeeper ClusterIP 172.30.176.187 2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP 17d hono-poc-zookeeper-headless ClusterIP None 2181/TCP,2888/TCP,3888/TCP 17d]

ROUTES
[image]

Values overridden in initial helm install:

```
platform: openshift

kafka:
  podSecurityContext:
    enabled: false
  containerSecurityContext:
    enabled: false

  zookeeper:
    podSecurityContext:
      enabled: false
    containerSecurityContext:
      enabled: false

useLoadBalancer: false

deviceRegistryExample:
  type: "mongodb"
  externalAccess:
    enabled: true

mongoDBBasedDeviceRegistry:
  externalAccess:
    enabled: true

mongodb:
  createInstance: true
  persistence:
    enabled: false

kafka:
  externalAccess:
    autoDiscovery:
      enabled: false
    service:
      type: "NodePort"
      # length of the array must match replicaCount
      nodePorts:
      - "32094"
  serviceAccount:
    create: false
  rbac:
    create: false

adapters:
  amqp:
    enabled: true
  coap:
    enabled: false
  http:
    enabled: true
  mqtt:
    enabled: true
  lora:
    enabled: false
enter code here
```

Comment: what command are you using to (successfully) connect to the Sandbox' AMQP adapter?

Comment: @KaiHudalla This command `java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar amqp -H hono.eclipseprojects.io -P 5672 -u sensor1@DEFAULT_TENANT -p hono-secret`

Answer (score 1):

You should omit the `https://` prefix from the host name and you will also need to provide a username and password for authenticating to the AMQP adapter using the `-u` and `-p` options:

```bash
java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar amqp -H hono-poc-adapter... -P 5672 -u sensor1@DEFAULT_TENANT -p hono-secret
```

Comment: Still getting the same result. `java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar amqp -H hono-poc-adapter-amqp-hono-poc.apps.iod-x.net -P 5672 -u TEST_DEVICE@TEST_TENANT -p pwd Failed to connect to Hono's AMQP adapter Error: 503 - Temporarily unavailable` I am able to post telemetry to the HTTP adapter for this tenant and I have enabled the AMQP adapter for the tenant.

Comment: Could it be because I don't have a consumer?

Comment: No, IIRC then OpenShift's Route concept only works for TLS based traffic using SNI. This basically means that you cannot access the plain TCP based AMQP endpoint on port 5672 but must use the TLS secured endpoint on 5671. For that to work, you will also need to configure the client to use a trust store that contains the CA of the AMQP adapter's server certificate. Or, much easier, deploy to plain k8s instead of OpenShift ...

Comment: I got around it by adding a pod to our Hono cluster and running the CLI from there (see other answer). We are stuck with OpenShift I'm afraid. Is it not recommended?

Comment: I would not say that it is not recommended. In fact, it is supposed to be a k8s implementation and then some ... However, I am not very familiar with OpenShift and can therefore not provide much help here.

Answer (score 0):

I have still not been able to connect using the CLI from my local computer, but since the protocol gateway should run in the cluster anyway I deployed a container with the Hono CLI installed and ran the CLI from the pods terminal, which worked.

```
java -jar hono-cli-*-exec.jar amqp -H hono-adapter-amqp -P 5672 -u TEST_DEVICE@TEST_TENANT -p pwd
```

"hono-adapter-amqp" in this case is the service name of the amqp-adapter in OpenShift, the IP also worked but the route did not.